# Deleting a pointer in C++ : what does `delete p` mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,4,2,3,5,6};
    int *p = arr;
    delete p;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6; i++)
        cout << p[i];

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `142356`. 
When I say `delete p` why doesn't this delete p?

Shouldn't there be segmentation fault when I run the code?

Comment: *Shouldn't there be segmentation fault when I run the code?* No, there should be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ta.speot.is So, the output `142356` is because of undefined behaviour?

Comment: *Any* behavior you observe when running this program should be regarded as sheer coincidence.

Comment: @larsmans @ta.speot.is okay. Also, when I delete `p`, why doesn't that delete the array `arr[]` which is being pointed by `p`. I mean deleting a pointer essentially frees the memory it points to, right?

Comment: I think the downvotes are not too well-placed here.

Comment: @Jatin how do you understand *freeing* the memory? To free memory is to mark it as allocable again.

Comment: @Jatin You need to go through a C++ book on [dynamic memory allocation](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Cpp-DynamicMemory.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a wise old chinese monk once said, 'Undefined behaviour is undefined'.

Seriously, attempting to `delete` something that wasn't `new`d is undefined.

c and c++ both define the majority of their unexpected functionality as 'undefined'. This means when you have such behaviour you have no idea what will happen. If you're really lucky it will seg fault or similar. More usually, weird and inexplicable things will happen and attempting to reason about them is largely pointless.

The main reason for this is so the implementation of the compiler can be both simpler and also more optimal.

As a C++ programmer, I'd recommend you reading up on Undefined Behaviour, Unspecified Behaviour and Implementation Defined Behavoir. They're all fundamental to understanding how any moderately interesting piece of c++ code will function.

The LLVM project's [blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) on undefined behavoir is a great read

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behaviour.

```
 int arr[] = {1,4,2,3,5,6};
 int *p = arr;
 delete p;
```

Here, `arr` is created not dynamically allocated. Even your pointer `p` is not dynamically allocated. You cannot use `delete` on it. `delete` [or `delete[]`] is used when you use `new` [or `new[]`] to allocate it and then use `delete` to release the dynamically allocated memory.

Defining a pointer (or declaring) doesnot cause memory to be allocated. You use `new`

```
int * p = new int;  //later deleted as delete p;
```

or

```
int * p = new int[5]; //later deleted as delete[] p;
```

etc.

to allocate memory and later delete it.
(Also, the number of `new` and `delete` must be equal and corresponding in your code)

Answer (score 1):

You are using "undefined behaviour", in this case using a pointer after free (and freeing something that hasn't come from new) - C++ (like C) is designed to be fast. Therefore, it doesn't do "unnecessary" things, such as checking what the memory is or filling memory with something else when you delete an object. It simply marks that memory as "free", and when you later allocate something else it will (or may choose to) use that memory for the new allocation.

If you have a class instead of a simple `int`, you could make the destructor write to the member variable(s) of the class and get it cleared. But for built-in types such as `int`, `long`, `double`, etc, nothing gets done.

Beware that undefind behaviour is just that - undefined. It can and will do other things than what you may expect - but it may also do perfectly what you expect. Part of that depends on what you expect. The point is that the standard doesn't say what will happen when you do something (e.g. the standard does not state that "Using memory that has been freed using delete must lead to a crash" or "memory freed by delete must be set to value X" - it also doesn't say that use of freed memory CAN'T cause a crash, or that the memory can't be changed to some new value.

Likewise, the standard doesn't say what you should expect if you free something that hasn't been allocated with new. Instead, it says that it's "undefined behaviour". Most likely, if you now go try to use `new`, it may well fail, because your heap has got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` operator is meant to inform whoever manages the memory, that the allocated memory, which address is stored in deleted pointer, is no longer needed by the program and can be freed.

Remember, that C++ is not only compiled for Win32 or Linux. There may be a lot more platforms, which manage their memory differently. This is why standard does not define explicitly, what should happen to freed memory. In your particular case memory was marked as free (if you allocated and filled another array of that size, the previous, freed one *may* have been overwritten, but not necessarily), but its contents were not destroyed.

Such implementation of memory management serves the purpose of performance: what is the point of overwriting freed memory with zeros (or other values), if it will be soon used again and filled with another data?

Now why your attempts to read from that memory didn't caused an AV? Possibly, because the whole block of memory, where that array resided was reserved for your process, so it was still attempting to read from its own memory. I **guess**, that attempt to write to that memory might have resulted in AV (but may have not, it is also implementation-specific).

The general rule is simply not to use memory freed by delete, because - as standard says - you have no guarantees neither about its accessibility, nor about its contents after it was freed.